# "Null check operator used on a null value in flutter, getx package"

Tags: flutter, dart

This class has functions for getting screen width and height, For app responsiveness design but i keep getting that error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

/*
This class has functions for getting screen width and height,
For app responsiveness design
*/
class AppLayout {
  static getSize(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  }

  static getScreenHeight() {
    return Get.height;
  }

  static getScreenWidth() {
    return Get.width;
  }

  static getHeight(double pixels) {
    double x = getScreenHeight() / pixels;
    return getScreenHeight() / x;
  }

  static getWidth(double pixels) {
    double x = getScreenWidth() / pixels;
    return getScreenWidth() / x;
  }
}
```

i was trying to keep my application screen responsive by using a getx package, i already installed the latest package and import it successfully but i keep getting error when i save it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine but you need to add empty value check -> (!) in all values.

Comment: i update my code but still get an error